# Multiple replacement

Tags: javascript, cloudflare-workers

Notice the following code

```
async function handleRequest(req) {
  const res = await fetch(req)
  return rewriter.transform(res)
}

 class AttributeRewriter {
  constructor(attributeName) {
    this.attributeName = attributeName
  }

  element(element) {
    const attribute = element.getAttribute(this.attributeName)
    if (attribute) {
      element.setAttribute(
        this.attributeName,
        attribute.replace('/product/', '/p-'),

      )
    }
  }
}

const rewriter = new HTMLRewriter()
  .on('a', new AttributeRewriter('href'))
  .on('link', new AttributeRewriter('href'))



addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
})
```

This code works fine
Description: I will replace **/product/** with **/p-** with this code
Now I'm going to replace these **a.com** values ​​with **b.com** and **static.a.com** with **cdn.b.com**
I'm going to replace them all in this code

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand the problem is that you’d like to do multiple string replacements on the href attributes of all  and  elements. Specifically, you’d like to replace /product/ with /p and you’d also like to replace a.com with b.com and static.a.com with cdn.b.com.

If that’s the case, then one simple approach would be to chain additional .replace() calls for each replacement you’d like to make. For example, something like this might work:

```
element.setAttribute(
  this.attributeName,
  attribute
    .replace('/product/', '/p-')
    .replace('//a.com/', '//b.com/')
    .replace('//static.a.com/', '//cdn.b.com/')
)
```

With this code, href="http://a.com/product/name" would be replaced with href="http://b.com/p-name".

I hope this helps!
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/multiple-replacement/152668/2